# Copying documentation and images from apache2 license

Tags: licensing, legal-terms, open-source-software

I am software developer and I wrote framework that is based on the same concepts as framework that is available in different language.

This framework is under Apache2 License and I want to copy big part of documentation that describing the main concepts and also the images.

Is this legal? Will credits at the bottom of the documentation enough?

Comment: The documentation may be licensed separately, have you verified that the documentation is under the same Apache2 license?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is legal, provided the documentation is made available for adaption and distribution under the same framework.

If it isn't, any entity using the [Apache 2.0 License](https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0) for software will be inclined to use a similar license with similar freedoms for downstream recipients for its documentation (i.e. [GFDL](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/fdl-1.3.en.html) or [Creative Commons BY-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)) - but it is worth checking out.

Provided the documentation is made available under the Apache 2.0 License, the section "How to apply the Apache License to your work" [at the bottom this page](https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0) tell you how to comply.

Also read the section "Redistribution" higher up on the page. It tells you what to retain to satisfy the copyright and attribution requirements of the work you are building upon.